# Landscape OpenStack Installation Requirements Checklist

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying a Openstack Install using Landscape, with MAAS and a set of KVM/virt-manager virtual machines.

The VMs have worked well with MAAS, and the Landscape install on a VM successfully completed.

Logging into Landscape, my checklist looks like this:

Registered a MAAS region controller (green checkmark)
Connection to the MAAS region controller available (green checkmark)
At least 5 machines with more than one disk have been commissioned (red X)
At least one of the commissioned machines, with mutliple disks must also have multiple network connections (greyed-out checkmark)

My first attempt - I didn't have the required VMs in a Ready state in MAAS. I added them, hoping that Landscape would detect them and let me proceed.  5 in all with 2 virtual disks and one of the 5 with 2 MAAS networks.  But that didn't help. So I reinstalled a Landscape VM, thinking maybe it needed to have them ready up front. No luck there either. The 3rd part of the checklist sounds like it's successful, but, why the red X?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My disks are virtio. I will change that and go through the enlist/commission process again.

Answer (score 8):

Not a 100% complete answer since I may need more details.  Please comment here if you have anything updated you need me to look at.  But, I think this could be your issue.

1. The checklist is dynamic, it will compute again when you reload the page.  You will *not* need to re-install landscape.  I suspect you probably did try to reload the page already -- I'm just putting this here so it's clear.
2. The red X is letting you know that landscape or MAAS thinks the machine doesn't have enough disks.  This information is parsed from the lshw tool.
3. Since I've hit this before, I *suspect* you are running into: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1355309

Could you please make sure your disks are not using the `virtio` driver and try again?  You will need to re-commission in MAAS, perhaps re-enlist (delete, re-add).  This is just a setting in the VM, so changing it there at least is easy, but in MAAS the hardware information needs to be refreshed.

The good news is: if you have landscape installed and at the checklist, you should not need to go through that process again.

Comment: I removed the virtio disks and added IDE disk in virt-manager. Then recommissioned in MAAS. The Landscape checklist is now all green.  Thanks.