# Problem with Checklist status on Landscape in Ubuntu Openstack - Canonical Distribution

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I've completed almost all steps about the installation of Canonical Distribution realized it on an Virtual Environment.

At the end the procedure I see Landscape Dashboard deployed of Juju. This is the situation of MaaS

[image]

while Landscape

[image]

[image]

if I scrolled down the page the result has been that

[image]

I've added the second HD on all the VM and re-put them in ready state on MaaS, then I've run Openstack with Landscape.... but the error is always the same.

How do I have to upgrade the configuration to see also the second disk and resolve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone can say me why on Landascape's dashboard receive that? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution

[Landscape OpenStack Installation Requirements Checklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562662/landscape-openstack-installation-requirements-checklist)

changed the bus disk from virtio in IDE on virt-manager for each vnode I've resolved that.

[image]

Now all Checklist are green

[image]